Unsigned smallint as primary key in Ent ORM for golang
I am trying to implement Ent ORM for my go project, but I encountered a problem while creating the database structure.
I have this first table which has an unsigned small int as primary key
package schema

import (
    "entgo.io/ent"
    "entgo.io/ent/schema/edge"
    "entgo.io/ent/schema/field"
)

type CharacterizationTechnique struct {
    ent.Schema
}

// Fields of the CharacterizationTechnique.
func (CharacterizationTechnique) Fields() []ent.Field {
    return []ent.Field{
        field.Uint16("characterization_technique_id").
            Unique(),
        field.String("characterization_technique").
            NotEmpty(),
        field.String("characterization_abbreviation").
            Optional().
            Nillable(),
        field.String("characterization_IS_unit").
            Optional().
            Nillable(),
    }
}

// Edges of the CharacterizationTechnique.
func (CharacterizationTechnique) Edges() []ent.Edge {
    return []ent.Edge{
        edge.To("lattices", Lattice.Type).
            StorageKey(edge.Column("characterization_technique_id")),
    }
}

And this other detail table that has a foreign key
package schema

import (
    "entgo.io/ent"
    "entgo.io/ent/schema/edge"
    "entgo.io/ent/schema/field"
)

type Lattice struct {
    ent.Schema
}

// Fields of the Lattice.
func (Lattice) Fields() []ent.Field {
    return []ent.Field{
        field.Uint32("lattice_id").
            Unique(),
        field.Uint16("characterization_technique_id").
            Optional().
            Nillable(),
        field.Float("a").Optional().Nillable(),
        field.Float("b").Optional().Nillable(),
        field.Float("c").Optional().Nillable(),
    }
}

// Edges of the Lattice.
func (Lattice) Edges() []ent.Edge {
    return []ent.Edge{
        edge.From("characterization_technique", CharacterizationTechnique.Type).
            Ref("lattices").
            Field("characterization_technique_id").
            Unique(),
    }
}

When trying to generate the go code it throws me this error
entc/gen: set "CharacterizationTechnique" foreign-keys: mismatch field type between edge field "characterization_technique_id" and id of type "CharacterizationTechnique" (uint16 != int)
exit status 1
internal\interfaces\persistence\ent\generate.go:3: running "go": exit status 1

I know a int is the default value Ent ORM uses to manage the foreign keys, but shouldn't I be able to specify is a small int unsigned? Am I doing something wrong or omitting something?
Edit
I tried extracting the ID but I still have the same problem
// ID method overrides the default ID configuration.
func (CharacterizationTechnique) ID() ent.Field {
    return field.Uint16("characterization_technique_id")
}


fix:

CharacterizationTechnique add primary key field.Uint16("id").Unique()
CharacterizationTechnique reset StorageKey valus to any.

// Fields of the CharacterizationTechnique.
func (CharacterizationTechnique) Fields() []ent.Field {
    return []ent.Field{
        field.Uint16("id").
            Unique(),
        field.String("characterization_technique").
            NotEmpty(),
        field.String("characterization_abbreviation").
            Optional().
            Nillable(),
        field.String("characterization_IS_unit").
            Optional().
            Nillable(),
    }
}

// Edges of the CharacterizationTechnique.
func (CharacterizationTechnique) Edges() []ent.Edge {
    return []ent.Edge{
        edge.To("lattices", Lattice.Type).
            StorageKey(edge.Column("characterization_technique_id_xxxxxxxx")),
    }
}

Explain
When binding a foreign key relationship in the setupFieldEdge method, force the ID column to be used for foreign key binding.
if t1, t2 := tf.Type.Type, fkOwner.Type.ID.Type.Type; t1 != t2 {
    return fmt.Errorf("mismatch field type between edge field %q and id of type %q (%s != %s)", fkName, fkOwner.Type.Name, t1, t2)
}

In the gen.NewType function, set the ID column name to id. The name cannot be modified, but the id option can be set.
NewType source
func NewType(c *Config, schema *load.Schema) (*Type, error) {
    typ := &Type{}
    if !typ.IsView() {
        typ.ID = &Field{
            cfg:  c,
            typ:  typ,
            Name: "id", // set name is id
            def: &load.Field{
                Name: "id",
            },
            Type:      idType,
            StructTag: structTag("id", ""),
        }
    }

    for _, f := range schema.Fields {
        tf := &Field{}

        // if name equal id, override the id Field option
        if typ.ID != nil && tf.Name == typ.ID.Name {
            typ.ID = tf
        } else {
            typ.Fields = append(typ.Fields, tf)
            typ.fields[f.Name] = tf
        }
    }
    return typ, nil
}

Therefore, if the ID column does not exist in the schema definition, it will be automatically added, otherwise it will be set as an option.
When CharacterizationTechnique.id(int) and Lattice.characterization_technique_id(uint16) are bound to foreign keys, the types are different and the ID column type is uint16 required.
CharacterizationTechnique.characterization_technique_id(uint16) and Lattice.characterization_technique_id(uint16) are not related.
StorageKey only modifies the foreign key column name. You can view the foreign key column in the generated ent/migrate/schema.go.
How to modify the primary key ID?

Gen hooks invalid


After gen.NewGraph calls gen.NewType, the foreign key binding (setupFKs) is executed. This is a continuous process and the Hooks are not run.


Schema Config define


gen.NewType does not have a process to modify the ID name. and func ID() ent.Field is not used.


Github issue


I saw a similar Issue 3907 that was not resolved.


I don't know


When I was about to give up, I thought of using Hook to rename the ID to characterization_technique_id. In Golang, it is still ID(template uses a constant ID), and the database column may be characterization_technique_id.
I don’t know if there are other side effects. It is recommended to modify your primary key column.
func HookTableRenameColumn(prefix string) gen.Hook {
    return func(next gen.Generator) gen.Generator {
        return gen.GenerateFunc(func(g *gen.Graph) error {
            for _, node := range g.Nodes {
                if node.Name == "CharacterizationTechnique" {
                    node.ID.Name = "characterization_technique_id"
                }
            }

            return next.Generate(g)
        })
    }
}



